# Rails Not In - Amistad Gem - Not selecting people that have blocked you or you have blocked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, amistad

Using the amistad  gem I can get People.all

After reviewing the documentation it looks like

```
People.blockades and People.blockades_by
```

returns the people that have blocked you and the people you have blocked

https://github.com/raw1z/amistad/wiki

Is it possible to return a query of all the people except those you have blocked and those that have blocked you? i have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out to no avail. Where you are a, and

```
a = People.first # or any person, really
```

With normal SQL one could do a not in query but I can't figure this out with rails.

## What I tried

```
People.where(:condition => "id NOT IN #{ids.join(',')}")
```

## ERROR

```
: SELECT "peoples".* FROM "peoples"  WHERE "peoples"."condition" = 'id NOT IN 11,106'
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column peoples.condition does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "peopless".* FROM "peopless"  WHERE "peoples"."condi...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you query you would need something like:

```
People.where('id NOT IN (?)', ids)
```

where `ids` is an array of id numbers (e.g. `[11,106]`)

Now, I don't know `amistad`, but you might want to try doing a simple subtraction to get your require list of people.  Something like:

```
People.all - People.blockades - People.blockades_by
```

Comment: Why do you suggest subtraction what is the benefit? My query is more complex. so it is People.where(:thing => "correct").where('id NOT IN (?)', ids)